# How do I prevent my Canon Selphy CP1300 from cropping my photos without getting a big border?

Tags: canon, aspect-ratio, printer

My smartphone takes photos with a different ratio from the one of the printer Canon Selphy CP1300 (10x15 cm).

When I print the photo using the "Canon PRINT Inkjet/SELPHY" app on my phone using the default `Borderless` configuration, the printer cuts the photo vertically. When I configure it as `Bordered`, the printer adds a big border both horizontally and vertically!

How can I tell the printer to print the photo as big as possible without cropping it (that is, with zero height border and minimal horizontal border)?

pd: if possible, without using a photo editor software to add a dummy horizontal border in order to get the same ratio as the printer.

Comment: Is there a "fit to page" option in the printer's menu/settings?

Comment: Are you printing from a computer or your phone?

Comment: Do you get borders when you print  a test image that has the right (3:2) ratio?

Comment: @MichaelC, no there is not.

Comment: @inkista, from the smartphone, as explained in the question.

Comment: i ended up taking photos with less zoom and installing an app to crop the image to 3:2 ratio.

Comment: I used to be a technical writer. "app" _can_ also mean a desktop application. :) Thanks for answering! Keep in mind on SE, comments are considered ephemeral and fleeting and can be deleted at any time. You may want to [edit your question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/103346/edit) (the link's below the tags) to add any additional information that's requested in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the editor in the **Canon PRINT Inkjet/SELPHY** mobile app. Cropping in the app's editor will not crop the image file in your camera roll.

When you've selected the image and are at the Print button window:

1. Tap the **Edit image** button.
2. Tap on the crop icon button at the bottom of the screen.
3. Set the Crop checkbox.
4. Tap **Crop size**.
5. Select the paper size you're using, **4"x6" 10x15cm**.
6. Select the appropriate crop orientation radio button.
7. Close the tab.
8. Tap **Back**.
9. Check that you have set the Border to **Borderless**. If you haven't, tap **Change Settings** to access the Border setting and change it.
10. Tap **Print**.

Comment: the app tells that this function is not available for my printer "Canon Selphy CP1300".

Comment: @DavidPortabella, sorry. I don't have a Selphy CP1300, I have a Pixma Pro-100, and it worked there; I just assumed it would work the same from the app. You could post your solution of finding a different app to crop with as answer. Answering your own questions is totally legit on SE.

Comment: i have the same issue when i use the app " editing function is not available for the selected printer selphy cp 1300"

Answer (score 0):

There’s actually another app you can use that will process the image and “Fit to page” called Selphy Layout. Why Canon would not combine this with the printer app is a mystery.

Comment: thanks. I've tried this application, and when you ask without border, it cuts both vertically and horizontally, very stupid app, haha. (to remove a border to fit a different ratio, it's necessary to cut only horizontally, or only vertically, but not both).

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been struggling with this for what feels like forever and I just cracked the code and my pics print out EXACTLY HOW I WANT THEM. I love my canon printer but the cropping features on its app suck ass. I found an app called “IMAGE SIZE” you put in the dimension 4x6 and send it to the printer in the app. I will never use cannons app again unless it’s for a collage.

Comment: Hi Deanna, welcome to Photo-SE. Is this the app you're talking about: https://www.image-size.com?